# Create a file from the browser

Tags: c#, browser, operating-system

I'm looking for a way to establish a simple communication between a c# web application and the operating system.

Since i'm working on Silverlight, i get everything i need to create files into any folder on the C:/ Disk. The problem is that we're going to migrate from Silverlight to Html 5 / C#

So i'd need a way to create files FROM any browser to any OS : Windows,Mac,Linux ..

I thought about using Microsoft Active X but that's not cross platforms.

I'm simply looking for a technology/plugin/software or anything that would allow me to do that, the less client interaction would be the best.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp may be what you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

I think your need is in conflict with any common sense about security. If there was a simple way to create any file on any computer that loads your web app, just imagine how quickly all sorts of malware would spread.

But going back to your question - I think it will not be simple (btw. was it really simple in silverlight?). What I can imagine is to have some kind of service running on a client PC (the user would have to install it, or it could be corporate policy if your web app is targeted at corporate solutions). Then the service would listen on some TCP port and your web app could send requests to that port with the intent to create particular file with particular content. All the security concerns would be then implemented in mentioned service so that it doesn't get abused by hostile web apps